# Android: Create Form Layout

Tags: android, forms, layout

How do I create a layout similar to this one in Android:

[image]

I have tried using TableLayout but it didn't go as expected because the Rows take the width of the largest one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using horizontal linear layouts inside of a veritcal linear layout. Also, you could try creating a custom listitem and using a listview to create the rows you desire